Return an empty AsyncIterable from a function
I would like to define a function returning an empty AsyncIterable of a concrete type.
The function will be a part of a base class; derived classes can implement it as necessary but the default behaviour is to return no items to iterate.
Unfortunately there is no convenient "default value" for the concrete type.
The code has to pass mypy's type checking and ideally pylint.
The following attempts do not work:
async def nope() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    pass  # error: Missing return statement  [empty-body]
# same with plain 'def'

async def nope() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    return  # error: Return value expected  [return-value]
# same with plain 'def'

(Found at Empty asynchronous iterable function):
async def nope() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    yield from () # error: "yield from" in async function

def nope() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    yield from () # error: The return type of a generator function should be "Generator" or one of its supertypes  [misc]

This works for int but there is no suitable default value for my concrete type. Besides, Pylint warns against a constant conditional:
async def nope() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    if False: yield 1 # W0125: Using a conditional statement with a constant value (using-constant-test)

What is a simple and understandable way to define a function returning an empty async iterable?

One alternative approach is to yield after an unconditional return:
async def nope() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    return
    yield

Demo: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=657740bc62191070286f954a6ed31508

I am surprised that neither mypy nor pylint complain about yield with no int argument.

This is because modern type checkers perform static analysis of execution paths and are able to determine that the yield statement here is unreachable and would therefore ignore its returning value.

Just because they could, does it mean they should?

Anything after an unconditional return is logically isconsequential so I would agree with the decision to ignore them.

I don't like that decision (i.e. TypeScript complains on equivalent code) but it's understandable.

Pylint must recognise this single yield as a special case because adding another yield gives an "Unreachable code" warning.

turns out mypy just follows the bytecode: Python doesn't produce anything after an unconditional return, if 1 == 1 defeats it, mypy sees more bytecode and starts showing errors there.

Good catch. This is indeed a common enough pattern to define an empty generator such that it is special-cased by pylint, which is designed to catch bad code patterns rather than to type check.

I don't think mypy is able to evaluate 1 == 1 statically, so it doesn't treat the block as an unconditional path.

There has to be a yield inside that never executes:
async def nope() -> AsyncIterable[int]:
    never: Never # required by mypy
    for never in ():
        yield never

Unfortunately this is rather wordy.
